# Prove that the incident axioms are independent

Tags: geometry, axioms, philosophy

Prove that the incident axioms are independent, that is:

Indicate  geometry model such that:

- b) the l2 axiom does not hold and the l1 and l3 axioms do

I1. For any two distinct points A, B there exist a unique line l containing A, B.

I2. Every line contains at least two points.

l3. There exist three noncollinear points (that is, three points not all contained in a single line).

Anyone have any idea?

what about case b)?

Comment: What is case b?

Comment: the l2 axiom does not hold and the l1 and l3 axioms do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This geomtery will do. Points $A$, $B$, $C$ fulfill L3, The lines $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ satisfy L1. The line $\ell_0$ defy L2.